# Eclipse/Luna: Where is SDK Manager?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, eclipse-luna

I just installed the new Luna Eclipse (I used to use Kepler). Can someone tell me where is the SDK Manager in Eclipse Luna version?

Comment: Which SDK? Android, Eclipse, ....?

Comment: The one for Android, accessed through eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find Android SDK Manager through install: ADT
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html

Answer (score 2):

You would need to install the official [plugin for Luna](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.4), mentioned in the [download page](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download):

```
https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.4
```